# How can I simulate click event with enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I would like to simulate a click on the button that sets currentPageIndex to currentPageIndex - 1 and match previous state to current state. 
The simulate method does not work.

```
it("sets state when previous button clicked", () => {
      const randomProps = randomPaginationProps();
      const wrapper = setup(Pagination, randomProps);
      const componentState = wrapper.state();
      const prevButton = findByTestAttribute(wrapper, "prev");
      console.log(componentState.currentPageIndex);
      prevButton.simulate("click");
      // outputs the same currentPageIndex as above console.log
      console.log(componentState.currentPageIndex);
    });

//helper methods in different file
export const setup = (Component, props = {}, state = null) => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Component {...props} />);
  if (state) wrapper.setState(state);
  return wrapper;
};

export const findByTestAttribute = (wrapper, val) => {
  return wrapper.find(`[data-test="${val}"]`);
};
// return method of rendered component
return (
      <div data-test="pagination" className="pagination">
        <button
          data-test="prev"
          className="change-page-btn"
          onClick={() => this.changePageButtonHandler("prev")}
          disabled={currentPageIndex === 0}
        >
          Prev
        </button>
        {pagination}
        <button
          data-test="next"
          className="change-page-btn"
          onClick={() => this.changePageButtonHandler("next")}
          disabled={currentPageIndex === pages.length - 1}
        >
          Next
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When  `console.log(prevButton.debug())`, it shows the below output. So the button is there, so to speak.

```
 <button data-test="prev" className="change-page-btn" onClick={[Function: onClick]} disabled={false}>
      Prev
    </button>
```

---

> Simulate events on the root node in the wrapper. It must be a single-node wrapper.

That's what the docs are saying. Maybe I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
prevButton.prop("onClick")();
```